# How to pass a function as parameter

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have two methods that are mostly the same, so I'm thinking of refactoring them.

A simple version is:

```
void C::GetEmailAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& alertSet)
{
  ...
  ... 
  AlertPtr pAlert = Cache::Get()->GetAlert();
  for (...) {
    ...
    if (pAlert->isEmail())
      alertSet.insert(p);
  }
  ...
}

void C::GetMobileAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& alertSet)
{
  ...
  ... 
  AlertPtr pAlert = Cache::Get()->GetAlert();
  for (...) {
    ...
    if (pAlert->isMobile())
      alertSet.insert(p);
  }
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to make it like:

```
void C::GetAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& alertSet, ??? func) // How to pass a function as parameter?
{
  ...
  ... 
  AlertPtr pAlert = Cache::Get()->GetAlert();
  for (...) {
    ...
    if (pAlert->func())
      alertSet.insert(p);
  }
  ...
}
```

so that I just call:

```
C c;
c.GetAlerts(emailSet, isEmail);
c.GetAlerts(mobileSet, isMobile);
```

------------------------ EDIT -----------------------

Maybe a generic example is easier to demonstrate what I would like to have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int foo() { cout<<"in foo()"<<endl; }
    int bar() { cout<<"in bar()"<<endl; }
};

A *instance = new A();

struct C
{
public:
  void test1()
  {
    instance->foo();
  }
  void test2()
  {
    instance->bar();
  }

//  void test(???) // How to pass member function as a pointer?
//  {
//    instance->f();
//  }
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  c.test1();
  c.test2();

//  c.test(&A::foo);
//  c.test(&A::bar);

  return 0;
}
```

In this second example, I'd like to use `c.test(&A::foo);` to replace `c.test1()`, and maybe c.test2, c.test3, ...

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Why not have a single member function `Alert::isType` that takes an argument like `"email"` or `"mobile"`?

Comment: See http://www.warplife.com/tips/code/c++/member-pointers.html

Comment: did you take a look at `std::function`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends. If you are using C++11, you can use the `auto` type and then execute the parameter. Otherwise, you'd need to know if the function is an `int`, `void`, `char`, etc. and then execute the given parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If `isEmail` like this: `bool AlertPtr::isEmail()`, you should use the below code:

```
void C::GetAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& alertSet, bool (AlertPtr::*func)())
{
    ...
    ... 
    AlertPtr pAlert = Cache::Get()->GetAlert();
    for (...) {
        ...
        if (pAlert->func)
            alertSet.insert(p);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If the signature was `bool isEmail()` that would be a free function and a free function doesn't get called through an object instance (i.e., you'd call it like this `isEmail()` not `instance->isEmail()`).

Comment: @James Adkison, if isEmail like this: bool AlertPtr::isEmail()?

Comment: You are better use `static inline bool isEmail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cascading your `if (pAlert->isMobile())` and `if (pAlert->isEmail())` in the same function?

Using function pointer to deal with this problem seems way overengineering.

```
void C::GetAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& emailAlertSet, set<AlertPtr>& mobileAlertSet)
{
  ...
  ... 
  AlertPtr pAlert = Cache::Get()->GetAlert();
  for (...) {
    ...
    if (pAlert->isEmail()) {
      emailAlertSet.insert(p);
    else if (pAlert->isMobile()) {
      mobileAlertSet.insert(p);
    }

  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, however might not works in my actual code. e.g. I have another `FetchEmail()` in `GetEmailAlert()`, and `FetchMobile()` in `GetMobileAlert()`. Code structure are similar, just some function names are difference..

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple just use namespaces define each of them in a namespace and can easily access them with the scoop operator

Answer (score 0):

For who might interested, I finally figured out how to do it:

```
void C::GetAlerts(set<AlertPtr>& alertSet, bool (AlertClass::func)())
{
  ...
  if ((pAlert->*func)())
    ...
}
```

This is how we call this function:

```
C c;
c.GetAlerts(emailSet, &AlertClass::isEmail);
c.GetAlerts(mobileSet, &AlertClass::isMobile);
```

Full solution for the second example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int foo() { cout<<"in foo()"<<endl; }
    int bar() { cout<<"in bar()"<<endl; }
};

A *instance = new A();

struct C
{
public:
  void testFoo()
  {
    instance->foo();
  }
  void testBar()
  {
    instance->bar();
  }

  void test(int (A::*p)())
  {
    (instance->*p)();
  }
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  c.testFoo();
  c.testBar();

  c.test(&A::foo);
  c.test(&A::bar);

  return 0;
}
```